# Biot number - Heisler chart correlation

Tags: thermodynamics, dimensional-analysis

Hello I have a question about Biot number. I know that if **Bi > 0.1** we're using Heisler chart to calculate heat transfer else **Lumped capacitance method** can be used. However can we use Heisler chart **Bi < 0.1** also? I couldn't find any source about that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Heisler chart can be used at all values of the Biot number (dimensionless external heat transfer coefficient).  However, when the Biot number is low, the simple analytic lumped capacitance method allows you to determine the temperature vs time analytically without the need for the Heisler chart (or for an infinite sum solution).  At low Biot number, the heat transfer locally approaches the asymptotic behavior for constant heat flux, for which the lumped capacitance solution applies.

Comment: Thank you sir! This answer saved my day.

I just have one final question. In the exam (Heat Transfer final exam), the question also asks temperature at position x (x=depth from surface) and transferred energy. I know that there is a heisler chart for that but is there any lumped method to calculate these? As I know, lumped capacitance method is used only calculate center temperature where Bi < 0.1

Comment: For low Biot number, you can also develop analytic expressions for the temperature as a function of time and position by solving analytically for the case of constant wall heat flux.  This solution expresses the temperature as a function of time (but not position) plus a function of position (but not time).  I don't have a reference on this handy.  But, in Transport Phenomena by Bird et al, they solve a steady state convective heat transfer problem involving flow in a tube where the temperature is expressed as a function of axial position plus a function of radial position.